# How to use git.io for non github.com domain URL?

Tags: github

If you enter an URL that is not under github.com domain, git.io will warn you that URL must be from github.com.

However http://git.io/2048 goes to https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/. I tried my own Github Pages and it didn't work.

Comment: That URL redirects to `http://gabrielecirulli.github.com/2048/` which itself is another redirect.

Comment: So you want to use git.io to link to a place that git.io explicitly says you can't use their service link to? What does the first part of the question have to do with the second?

Comment: @David http://git.io/2048 does the trick. I just want to know how.

Comment: You want to know how... a URL redirect works?

Answer (score 4):

One more thing to note here, besides changing `.io` to `.com` is that if you create a short URL for a GitHub URL without providing a [custom](https://github.com/blog/985-git-io-github-url-shortener) [code](http://techno-weenie.net/guillotine/) argument, you won't be able to use [Git.io](http://git.io/) to shorten the same GitHub URL again with your custom code.

For instance I shortened https://1oh1.github.com using the [Git.io](http://git.io/) website without providing a custom code, so now I'm stuck with this: http://git.io/hWhKbw

However, I used [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to shorten the same URL again (this time without the "S" in "HTTPS" so it's a different URL) and provided a "code" argument:

```
curl http://git.io/ -i -F "url=http://1oh1.github.com" -F "code=1oh1"
```

That got me what I wanted:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Wed, 17 Sep 2014 08:30:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 201 Created
Location: http://git.io/1oh1
Content-Length: 23
X-Runtime: 0.008799
X-Node: gitio2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your normal github.io address but change the ".io" to ".com" (e.g. gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/ would be entered as gabrielecirulli.github.com/2048/).

Here's an article about the githup pages that explain the github.io vs githum.com relation as well: https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io

Comment: That explains how the 2048 link works, but it only applies to old GitHub Pages sites that precede the switch from `.github.com` to `.github.io`. If you try to access new GitHub Pages sites under `.github.com`, you get a 404 page saying:
"Subdomains of github.com [are deprecated](https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io) for GitHub Pages. They will not redirect to github.io for new GitHub Pages sites."